# python findall including optional text

Tags: python, regex, findall

I would like to extract values from a string similar to this:

```
=== START AAA
one: 11 
two: 22
=== START BBB
one: 44
two: 55
three: 66
```

The "three" parameter is optional.  I could parse line by line but I'm trying to do this with re.findall.  I added the .*? and the (===|$) so that the whole string wouldn't be consumed at once.  I have tried many things and this seems to get the closest:

```
stats_re = re.compile('START (\S+).*?one\s*:\s*(\S+).*?two\s*:\s+(\S+).*?(three\s*:\s+(\S+))?(===|$)',re.DOTALL)
```

This produces:

```
('AAA', '11', '22', '', '', '===')
('BBB', '44', '55', '', '', '')
```

which almost works except I'm not getting the value for the "three" parameter when it does appear.

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a parser instead.

Comment: I am not sure how you ran it, but I am getting something different: http://ideone.com/0i1vuI

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is mostly fine. You're missing a couple of things.
For the most part you have to use the consistent `.*?` to consume between fields.

I've commented the parts that needed to be modified.
This is the modified regex:

```
 START[ ]+(\S+).*?one\s*:\s*(\S+).*?two\s*:\s+(\S+).*?(?:three\s*:\s+(\S+).*?)?(===|$)
```

Expanded:

```
 START [ ]+                    # <- Added '+'
 ( \S+ )                       # (1)
 .*? one \s* : \s* 
 ( \S+ )                       # (2)
 .*? two \s* : \s+ 
 ( \S+ )                       # (3)
 .*? 
 (?:                           # <- Converted to non-capture
      three \s* : \s+ 
      ( \S+ )                       # (4)
      .*?                           # <- Added '.*?'
 )?
 ( === | $ )                   # (5)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 4 , len 33 ) 
START AAA
one: 11 
two: 22
===  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 10 , len 3 ) 
AAA  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 20 , len 2 ) 
11  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 30 , len 2 ) 
22  
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 34 , len 3 ) 
===  

--------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 38 , len 39 ) 
START BBB
one: 44
two: 55
three: 66   
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 44 , len 3 ) 
BBB  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 54 , len 2 ) 
44  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 63 , len 2 ) 
55  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 74 , len 2 ) 
66  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 77 , len 0 )  EMPTY
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works and is quite helpful.